# Custom Round UIButton with Round Image View

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimageview

I have created a custom class for an UIButton which I used to add round corners and drop shadow to my button also using @IBInspectable.

Now, I want to use the same button to create a round one for a profile image picker. The user taps on the round button, the Photo Library is presented, the user selects a photo and the selected image is added to the round button.

My issue is that after the user selects the image, the imageView of the button is square and not round.

I have tried to play with the button's imageView's layer and tried to set it to clipsToBounds or maskToBounds but I think I'm missing something.

Here is the code for the custom button without the ImageView stuff:

```
import UIKit

class RoundShadowButton: UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
    }


 @IBInspectable
     var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
         get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
         }
         set {
             layer.cornerRadius = newValue
         }
     }

     @IBInspectable
     var borderWidth: CGFloat {
         get {
             return layer.borderWidth
         }
         set {
             layer.borderWidth = newValue
         }
     }

     @IBInspectable
     var borderColor: UIColor? {
         get {
             let color = UIColor.init(cgColor: layer.borderColor!)
             return color
         }
         set {
             layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor
         }
     }

     @IBInspectable
     var shadowRadius: CGFloat {
         get {
             return layer.shadowRadius
         }
         set {
            layer.shadowRadius = newValue
         }
     }
     @IBInspectable
     var shadowOffset : CGSize{

         get{
             return layer.shadowOffset
         }set{
             layer.shadowOffset = newValue
         }
     }

     @IBInspectable
     var shadowColor : UIColor{
         get{
             return UIColor.init(cgColor: layer.shadowColor!)
         }
         set {
             layer.shadowColor = newValue.cgColor
         }
     }
     @IBInspectable
     var shadowOpacity : Float {

         get{
             return layer.shadowOpacity
         }
         set {
             layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
         }
     }
 }
```

[image: Button before selecting image]

[image: Button after selecting image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing that unless you're setting image for your button, button's `imageView` is `nil`. You should either set `maskToBounds` to your button, or set it to imageView after you set image. Also, please check your corner radius, if you have method based on your frame, during autolayout you can set your corner radius based on `.zero` frame

Comment: Unfortunately if I manipulate maskToBounds I cannot have drop shadow anymore. But thank you for the other suggestion!